# Dynamic Button control only appearing on last row

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having an issue where my Button control which is generated dynamically only appears on the last row.  I've looked at this post

[Asp.net Linkbutton loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488086/asp-net-linkbutton-loop)

but it suggests using a ListView which I don't think I can use in this case.  I generate an HTML table using a Panel control and SQL data and it gets pretty specific in my opinion. 
Here's my code behind:

```
//declare a dynamic button
    Button btn_continue = new Button();
    btn_continue.Click += Btn_continue_Click;
    btn_continue.CssClass = "controlButtons";
    btn_continue.Font.Size = 20;
    btn_continue.Text = "Continue this job";

    //formatting for the rows
    int oddNumber = 1;

    foreach (DataRow row in dtGetIncompleteJobs.Rows)
    {
        //grab the date and make it shorter
        DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(row[3].ToString());

        pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<tr>"));
        if (centralFunctions.OddNumberCheck(oddNumber) == true)
        {
            pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td class='col-1 col-1-m lightRow'>" + row[5].ToString() + "</td>"));
            pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td class='col-2 col-2-m lightRow'>" + date.ToShortDateString() + "</td>"));
            pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td class='col-2 col-2-m lightRow'>" + row[0].ToString() + "</td>"));
            pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td class='col-2 col-2-m lightRow'>" + row[1].ToString() + "</td>"));
            pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td class='col-2 col-2-m lightRow'>" + row[2].ToString() + "</td>"));
            pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td class='col-1 col-1-m lightRow'>" + row[4].ToString() + "</td>"));
            pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td class='col-2 col-2-m'>"));
            btn_continue.ID = row[5].ToString();
            pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(btn_continue);
            pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td>"));
            oddNumber++;
        }
        else
        {
            pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td class='col-1 col-1-m darkRow'>" + row[5].ToString() + "</td>"));
            pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td class='col-2 col-2-m darkRow'>" + row[3].ToString() + "</td>"));
            pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td class='col-2 col-2-m darkRow'>" + row[0].ToString() + "</td>"));
            pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td class='col-2 col-2-m darkRow'>" + row[2].ToString() + "</td>"));
            pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td class='col-2 col-2-m darkRow'>" + row[2].ToString() + "</td>"));
            pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td class='col-1 col-1-m darkRow'>" + row[4].ToString() + "</td>"));
            pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td class='col-2 col-2-m'>"));
            btn_continue.ID = row[5].ToString();
            pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(btn_continue);
            pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td>"));
            oddNumber++;

        }

        pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</tr>"));
    }
```

And here's what it looks like:
[html output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XObBd.png)

Is it possible to get the Button control on each row the way I'm doing it?  I have a feeling I'm either missing something simple or going down the wrong path.
Let me know if I left any details out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new button for each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to move your creation code for the btn_continue to withn the foreach loop

```
//formatting for the rows
int oddNumber = 1;

//declate the button
Button btn_continue
foreach (DataRow row in dtGetIncompleteJobs.Rows)
{
    //grab the date and make it shorter
    DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(row[3].ToString());

    //create the button
    btn_continue = new Button();
    btn_continue.Click += Btn_continue_Click;
    btn_continue.CssClass = "controlButtons";
    btn_continue.Font.Size = 20;
    btn_continue.Text = "Continue this job";

    pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<tr>"));
    if (centralFunctions.OddNumberCheck(oddNumber) == true)
    {
        pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td class='col-1 col-1-m lightRow'>" + row[5].ToString() + "</td>"));
        pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td class='col-2 col-2-m lightRow'>" + date.ToShortDateString() + "</td>"));
        pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td class='col-2 col-2-m lightRow'>" + row[0].ToString() + "</td>"));
        pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td class='col-2 col-2-m lightRow'>" + row[1].ToString() + "</td>"));
        pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td class='col-2 col-2-m lightRow'>" + row[2].ToString() + "</td>"));
        pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td class='col-1 col-1-m lightRow'>" + row[4].ToString() + "</td>"));
        pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td class='col-2 col-2-m'>"));
        btn_continue.ID = row[5].ToString();
        pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(btn_continue);
        pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td>"));
        oddNumber++;
    }
    else
    {
        pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td class='col-1 col-1-m darkRow'>" + row[5].ToString() + "</td>"));
        pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td class='col-2 col-2-m darkRow'>" + row[3].ToString() + "</td>"));
        pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td class='col-2 col-2-m darkRow'>" + row[0].ToString() + "</td>"));
        pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td class='col-2 col-2-m darkRow'>" + row[2].ToString() + "</td>"));
        pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td class='col-2 col-2-m darkRow'>" + row[2].ToString() + "</td>"));
        pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td class='col-1 col-1-m darkRow'>" + row[4].ToString() + "</td>"));
        pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td class='col-2 col-2-m'>"));
        btn_continue.ID = row[5].ToString();
        pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(btn_continue);
        pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td>"));
        oddNumber++;

    }

    pnl_jobList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</tr>"));
}
```

Comment: Wow, I knew it was something simple.  Not sure why it didn't work when I tried it before...In any case it works now. Thanks!!

Comment: @ryol - In your original code, you created only one button. So it could appear only once in the form, at the last position that you gave to it.